# Xdebug one applications triggers debug connection from other?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I have two separate Laravel 8 applications on my machine.
I set in the `.env` the setting `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug` and build the container with `no-cache` flag.

[image]

These are my PHP/DEBUG entries:

[image: SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug]

There are no entries at "PHP | Servers".

And here is the strangest thing that I can't explain to myself:

One container is listening to port localhost:89 (folder `app-a`) the other to localhost:8083 (folder `app-b`).

When I open project folder `app-a` with PhpStorm and set a breakpoint at index.php and also enable listening for debug connection, then nothing happens when I open up localhost:89. However, when I open localhost:8083 the debugging suddenly starts?
Why is the one application triggering the debug of my other application?

When I opening folder `app-b` with PhpStorm, then neither only localhost:8083  trigger the debug start (as expected).

Any ideas how this is possible? For the browser I use Chrome with Xdebug extension.

Comment: In `app-b`, do you have `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations enabled`? It's not PhpStorm that triggers debug sessions, they start because your servers see the debug cookie. Unless you have this option enabled, I don't see any reason why `app-b` would ignore debug sessions from `localhost:8083`.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov no the option is disabled, just as in the screenshot. Do configurations change depending on which project I have open? I checked for app-b and app-a, they both have same configuration and "servers" is empty.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I just tested it again and it seems that `app-b` is actually working. My problem is that I cannot debug `app-a`

Comment: @Adam Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say. Then compare to the same log with a working project. Do you see any difference? That's a starting point for you right now. It just difficult to suggest anything without knowing how it all set up there.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov having `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` enabled does prevent app-a from starting debuggin at app-b. It was caused because I did not had it enabled :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, that `app-b` caused debugging in `app-a` was because I had `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` disabled. Enabling this options prevents this.

The reason why `localhost:89` was not initializing the debug session, was because of my Laravel setup. I was using an older version of Laravel 8 initially (although I updated to latest version, the docker-compose file was copied from an older version of sail). In particular, I was missing the following entries:

```
 environment:
     WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
     LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
     XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
     XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-  client_host=host.docker.internal}'
extra_hosts:
     - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
```

Adding those entries, together with a debug plugin in browser made debugging work.